# Is it wrong to modify the list I am looping over if that's what I want?

Tags: python

I've read many times that it is A Bad Idea to loop over a list that you're modifying in the loop body, and for good reason. Does that also hold true in a case where

1. I am only appending new elements to the list, not removing items;
2. This is a behaviour that I actually want?

Here's my code: the "search" method is meant to collect the payload of all nodes that have the target label, apart from those that are descendants of nodes with the target label.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, label, payload, children):
        self.label = label # string
        self.payload = payload # some kind of data carried by the node
        self.children = children # list of Trees

    def search(self, target):
        nodes = [self]
        result = []
        for node in nodes:
            if node.label == target:
                result.append(node.payload)
            else:
                nodes += node.children
        return result
```

Is there anything wrong with this example? I could of course turn this into a recursive function or a while loop, but this seems the most elegant way (and I won't run into python's recursion depth limit).

Comment: You're not modifying the list. You're modifying elements in the list.

Comment: Doesn't `+=` create an entirely new array?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ -- Not true.  Look at `nodes += node.children`.  That  will add more elements to the list of `nodes`.

Comment: Adding to the end of a list isn't a problem.  The internal counter is checked against the current length of the list and the loop terminates when it's reached the current end.  So anything added to the end of the list will simply be included in the loop.  As long as you don't end up infinitely adding elements to the list (if node.children contains a reference to a previous node, for instance), your code is fine.  Replace += with .extend(), though.  Much much more efficient.

Comment: @AlanLeuthard -- `+=` and `.extend` for lists are roughly the same thing.  In reality, `+=` might be slightly _more_ efficient because the method lookup can be skipped.  Note that `lst += other_list` is _NOT_ the same thing as `lst = lst + other_list`.  (The latter _would_ be really inefficient and wouldn't work in this scenario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any huge landmines here from a logic perspective so I think you're OK.

From an algorithms/performance standpoint, you'd (probably) be better off using a Queue.  The advantages of a Queue rather than a list are:

- You don't pay resizing costs as the Queue grows
- You don't need to hold an additional reference to every node in the tree

Python provides a workable queue in `collections` that I'd recommend you use:

```
def search(self, target):
    queue = collections.deque([self])
    result = []
    while queue:
        node = queue.popleft()
        if node.label == target:
            result.append(node.payload)
        else:
            queue.extend(node.children)
    return result
```

We're only using one extra line of code and we have some better data structures so I'd recommend this approach. (Also, if you change `search` to a generator function, you can save 2 lines of code for a net decrease in lines)

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! But I think in the line `node = deque.popleft()` you mean `node = queue.popleft()`?

Comment: @AlexMcKenzie -- Yep, that's what I meant.  Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) says:

> An internal counter is used to keep track of which item is used next, and this is incremented on each iteration. When this counter has reached the length of the sequence the loop terminates.

Your code seems to be safe.

Comment: But is it "the current length of the sequence" or "the length of the sequnce at the beginning of the loop"? Apparently CPython does the former, but this  sentence is a little ambiguous.

Comment: @Błotosmętek -- I don't think that it can be reasonably interpreted as "the length of the sequence at the beginning of the loop".

Comment: The comparison is to len(list).  Since len(list) changes as the list changes, it compares to the current length, not the original length.